# Git wont let me commit because it "found a file by the name of '.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, github, git-commit

This happens every time i try to commit (not always but today). I don't have anything up on any window or anything. I looked up other similar questions on stack overflow and i did what they said but its still not working. I found and deleted the file but it makes a new one when i try to run 'git commit .'

Comment: If you commit without the `-m "comment"` flag, git tries to open an editor for you to enter the commit message. It seems that there is a problem with this editor. It opens a temporary file but does open the input display. Perhaps you could remove the swap file and use the -m flag with your next commit. If you already did this and it didn't work I have no further clue. It's always a good idea to explain what you've tried so far. Just, to avoid downvotes (this one is not by me) and to give me and other people here an idea of what could have happend ;-).

Comment: Hey i added it all in one line i did "git commit . -m "message" and it seemed to work then i pushed and everything went through !!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `*.swp` to your `.gitignore`, or manage globally via `~/.gitignore_global`:

```
*.swp
```

Comment: how do i add my .swp to my git ignore?